# Mips reading integer and store them in array then find the max

Tags: arrays, mips

again

I'm writing a MIPS program that reads 5 integers and stores them in array. It then creates a new array whose values are the values of the initial array multiplied with their index. After that I need to find the max and min of the second array.

I'm new to MIPS, here is the code I wrote  :

```
.data

Prompt: .asciiz "\n  Enter 5 Integers :" #gets number of integers
op: .asciiz "\n  Enter Option: \n 1-Find the mult \n 2- Find the max \n 3-Find the min  \n 4-Exit" 
invalidm: .asciiz "\n  Bad Input:" 
vec: .space 20
vec2: .space 20

.text 
.globl __start
__start:
la $a0,Prompt
li $v0,4
syscall

#Reading integers and store theme in the array 

options:
la $a0,op
li $v0,4
syscall

li $v0,5
syscall
blt $v0,1,invalid#
bgt $v0,4,invalid#
beq $v0, 1, multp#
beq $v0, 2, max#
beq $v0, 3, min#
beq $v0, 4, exitpro#
j options 


multp:
#multiply every element in the array with its index and store them in the new array vec2

j options

max:
#find the max of the array vec
j options

min:
#find the min of the array vec
j options

invalid:
la $a0,invalidm
li $v0,4
syscall
j options


exitpro:
li $v0,10
syscall
```

Comment: Is allocating the second array required, or do you just need the max/min of each element multiplied by its index? Further, is the index 0-based or 1-based? Finally, I'm confused by the point of trying to select the function via options, it seems like you only need it to do one thing. Why the extra complexity?

Comment: exactly, first i need to read the 5 integer elements and store them in the array then i need to do the multiply of each element with his index (1-based ) so no need for the second array (we can just print the result each time ) ,finally for the original array (vec ) i need to find the max integer number in it .... waiting for your replay my friend and thanks for the fast replay  .
all regards

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to make a quick note on coding style: assembly is a bit diabolical. It's very tempting to say "oh, I do these 5 lines a lot, I should just `jal` here and reuse it". This makes sense at first, but tends to result in confusing spaghetti code that can't go 3 lines without jumping somewhere. As such, my code has a bit of code repetition, but nothing too bad.

I altered your initial conditions a little, the length of the array is hard coded, but it uses a stack-allocated array rather than one that's statically allocated at initialization in the `.data` header. Instead the array's *length* is allocated in the `data` section. This was just personal preference. It has the benefit that the code should work for any length > 0.

```
.data

PromptHead: .asciiz "\n Enter "
PromptTail: .asciiz " integers\n"
Minstr:     .asciiz "Min: "
Maxstr:     .asciiz "Max: "
newline:    .asciiz "\n"

inputs: .word 5

.text

main:
    # Output prompt for input
    ## "\n Enter "
    la $a0, PromptHead
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    ## "5"
    lw $a0, inputs
    li $v0, 1
    syscall

    ## " integers\n"
    la $a0, PromptTail
    li $v0, 4
    syscall


    # Backup sp value before allocating array
    move $fp, $sp

    # calculate size of vector (numinputs * sizeof(int) = numinputs * 4 = numinputs << 2), store in $s1
    lw   $s0, inputs 
    sll  $s1, $s0, 2

    # dynamically grow stack to include array of ints
    add $sp, $sp, $s1

    # Loop initialization
    # i = 0
    move $s1, $zero
    # while i < numInputs
    ReadInput:
        slt $s2, $s1, $s0
        beq $s2, $zero, ReadInputDone

        # Read integer
        li $v0, 5
        syscall

        # Calculate array offset for this loop
        sll $s2, $s1, 2
        add $s2, $fp, $s2

        # Store array value at calculated address
        sw  $v0, 0($s2)

        # i++
        addi $s1, $s1, 1
        j ReadInput
    ReadInputDone:

    # Scale(array, length)
    move $a0, $fp
    move $a1, $s1
    jal  Scale

    # max = FindMax(array, length)
    jal  FindMax

    # Back up return val, print boilerplate
    move $t0, $v0
    li   $v0, 4
    la   $a0, Maxstr
    syscall

    move $a0, $t0
    li   $v0, 1
    syscall

    la $a0, newline
    li $v0, 4
    syscall


    # min = FindMin(array,length)
    move $a0, $fp
    jal  FindMin

    # Back up return val, print boilerplate
    move $t0, $v0
    li   $v0, 4
    la   $a0, Minstr
    syscall

    move $a0, $t0
    li   $v0, 1
    syscall

    la $a0, newline
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    # Exit program
    li $v0, 10
    syscall


# Scale(array, length)
# Scales each array element by index+1. This does not alter any s or a registers,
# Alters the array in place.
Scale:
    # Backup return address and fp on stack.
    # Not strictly necessary here, but usually good to do this by habit
    # when you're learning
    sw   $fp, 0($sp)
    sw   $ra, 4($sp)
    addi $fp, $sp, 8
    move $sp, $fp

    # Load arguments into scratch registers
    move $t0, $a0
    move $t1, $a1

    # Loop initialization as above
    # i = 0
    move $t2, $zero
    # while i < 5
    ScaleInput:
        slt $t3, $t2, $t1
        beq $t3, $zero, ScaleInputDone

        # Calculate element offset, store address in $t3
        sll $t3, $t2, 2
        add $t3, $t0, $t3

        # Load array element at $t3, multiply it by current index+1
        # Grab it from the multiplication register (assume no overflow)
        # then store the result back in the array
        lw   $t5, 0($t3)
        addi $t4, $t2, 1
        mult  $t5, $t4
        mflo $t5
        sw   $t5, 0($t3)

        # i++
        addi $t2, $t2, 1
        j ScaleInput
    ScaleInputDone:

    # Unwind stack, restore frame pointer and
    # return address. Again, not necessary here, but good
    # practice
    lw   $ra, -4($fp)
    move $sp, $fp
    lw   $fp, -8($fp)
    jr $ra


# int Max(array, length); result returned in $v0,
# No s or a registers are altered
FindMax:
    # Backup return address and fp on stack.
    sw   $fp, 0($sp)
    sw   $ra, 4($sp)
    addi $fp, $sp, 8
    move $sp, $fp

    # Load arguments into scratch registers
    move $t0, $a0
    move $t1, $a1

    # set currMin = array[0]
    lw $v0, 0($t0)

    # Loop initialization
    # i = 1
    li $t2, 1
    # while i < 5
    MaxLoop:
        slt $t3, $t2, $t1
        beq $t3, $zero, MaxLoopDone

        # Calculate element offset, store address in $t3
        sll $t3, $t2, 2
        add $t3, $t0, $t3

        # Load array element at $t3, check if it's the new max
        lw   $t4, 0($t3)
        sgt  $t5, $t4, $v0
        beq  $t5, $zero, notGreater

        # If so, set return value to it
            move $v0, $t4
        notGreater:

        # i++
        addi $t2, $t2, 1
        j MaxLoop
    MaxLoopDone:

    # Unwind stack
    lw   $ra, -4($fp)
    move $sp, $fp
    lw   $fp, -8($fp)
    jr   $ra


# int Min(array, length); result returned in $v0,
# No s or a registers are altered
FindMin:
    # Backup return address and fp on stack.
    sw   $fp, 0($sp)
    sw   $ra, 4($sp)
    addi $fp, $sp, 8
    move $sp, $fp

    # Load arguments into scratch registers
    move $t0, $a0
    move $t1, $a1

    # set currMin = array[0]
    lw $v0, 0($t0)

    # Loop initialization
    # i = 1
    li $t2, 1
    # while i < 5
    MinLoop:
        slt $t3, $t2, $t1
        beq $t3, $zero, MinLoopDone

        # Calculate element offset, store address in $t3
        sll $t3, $t2, 2
        add $t3, $t0, $t3

        # Load array element at $t3, check if it's the new min
        lw   $t4, 0($t3)
        slt  $t5, $t4, $v0
        beq  $t5, $zero, notLesser

        # If so, set return value to it
            move $v0, $t4
        notLesser:

        # i++
        addi $t2, $t2, 1
        j MinLoop
    MinLoopDone:

    # Unwind stack
    lw   $ra, -4($fp)
    move $sp, $fp
    lw   $fp, -8($fp)
    jr   $ra
```

As I mention in the code, the monkeying around with storing the `$ra` and `$fp` is a bit paranoid. If I was REALLY paranoid I'd store all the `s` registers as well. However, it's generally good practice and can save you a lot of headaches when you decide to add "function calls" in the middle of a function.

This is basically the approach to assembly where you write the program in C in your head and then translate that rather literally into assembly. Hence why I treat scaling, finding the max, etc as "functions".

A couple assemblyish notes: I repeatedly use `sll $register, $register, 2` instead of multiplying by 4 (word size on MIPS32). This is because doing this is fewer instructions due to not having to cal `li` followed by `mult` followed by `mflo`. You can do it that way, and I used to, but once you get used to using `sll` and other bit fiddling operations a lot it's just cleaner to use `sll` as well as easier to read.

I do use a few [pseudoinstructions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/Pseudoinstructions), it's not a big deal, most modern MIPS assemblers and simulators that I'm aware of support them (including SPIM). I dance dangerously with the line after branch instructions (which are theoretically always executed regardless of the branch result), but in this case it wouldn't usually matter and most simulators and assemblers usually inject a no-op for you when it does anyway.

I know assembly can be a bit of a pain to read, so feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Comment: While we are giving tips on style you should really think about indenting your code.

Comment: Huh, I guess it ate the tabs when I copied.

Comment: @KonradLindenbach There, I re-added them. I swear they were there locally.

Comment: wow , my friend that was great ,however the code run likw this :
Enter 5 Integers :
1
2
3
4
5
Max: 2147476640
Min: 2147476640

this is not the result i wanted ,the result i want is :
max: 5
Min: 1
multiplay by index: 1 4 9 16 25 

just that simple 

sorry to tell you that you had a lot of time typing the above code my friend I'm so sorry 
,please I'm asking you to modify it to work like that 

. so sorry again 
 all regards Jsor

Comment: @WissamEng It definitely worked on my SPIM, and I copy/pasted it. Not sure what's wrong. Are you sure you properly reset registers and loaded it from a blank session?

Comment: @WissamEng Also, I thought you wanted it scaled before you found the max/min. So 1,2,3,4,5 would give Max: 25 Min: 1. That's what the code does, if you get it working you can fix it by changing the order you call Max/Min and Scale in (you also have to print the array after scaling, which I leave up to you).

Comment: @Jsor , it printed the value 2147476640 for max and min when entering 1 2 3 4 5 , when it should print min:1 and max:25 , so that what the code print for you ? cuz that what i want as beginning then i can remove the multiply by index to find the max/min in the original array , once again thanks for the fast replay .

Comment: @WissamEng Yes, I just copied and pasted the code from here into a fresh file, loaded up SPIM, loaded the file, and ran it and it works correctly. So I have no idea what the problem is on your end.

Comment: @Jsor iwill try a newer version of spim cuz mine is old . anyway thanks for ever my friend that was very helpful .

all regards